# Background colour refuses to apply in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

This is a piece of code from my html email - in this section, the colour refuses to apply in outlook despite using bgcolor and the background style property

I have attached a screenshot of what it should look like

[image]

The td immediately above the title does not colour.

Any help would be great

```html
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="fe513e" class="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; background-color:#fe513e !important; font-size:1px; line-height:1px; margin-right:auto;" mc:repeatable mc:variant="Newsletter title">
  <tr>
    <td height="20" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; background-color:#fe513e !important;" bgcolor="#fe513e" class="fix_height"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" bgcolor="#fe513e" style="background-color:#fe513e !important;" class="hide"></td>
    <td class="pad_side">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #fe513e !important;" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#fe513e">
        <tr>
          <td class="black" align="center" bgcolor="#fe513e" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:0;line-height:25px;color:#ffffff; background-color:#fe513e !important;" mc:edit="newsletter_title_1">The Latest News for October 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="20" bgcolor="#fe513e" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px; background-color: #fe513e;" class="fix_height"> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="30" bgcolor="#fe513e" style="background-color: #fe513e !important" class="hide"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does it actually look like? What outlook-version are you using?

Comment: Try adding `colspan="3"` to the single `td`s above and below the row that had three `td`s

Comment: Yes this worked! I'm not sure who answered this first - though technically this answer was more accurate because it referenced the lower td - if you make this an answer I can accept it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Don't use `colspan`. Add two more `td` cells to match the rest of the table or use one `td` for each row and add in a separate `table`.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out the `#` when you set the table `bgcolor`, so Outlook for Desktop will not pick it up.

So this:

```
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="fe513e" class="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; background-color:#fe513e !important; font-size:1px; line-height:1px; margin-right:auto;" mc:repeatable mc:variant="Newsletter title">
```

Should be:

```
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#fe513e" class="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; background-color:#fe513e !important; font-size:1px; line-height:1px; margin-right:auto;" mc:repeatable mc:variant="Newsletter title">
```

Answer (score 0):

adding colspan="3" will make it perfect

```html
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#fe513e" class="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; background-color:#fe513e !important; font-size:1px; line-height:1px; margin-right:auto;" mc:repeatable mc:variant="Newsletter title">
    <tr>
      <td height="20" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; background-color:#fe513e !important;" colspan="3" bgcolor="#fe513e" class="fix_height"></td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="30" bgcolor="#fe513e" style="background-color:#fe513e !important;" class="hide"></td>
      <td class="pad_side">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #fe513e !important;" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#fe513e">
          <tr>
            <td class="black" align="center" bgcolor="#fe513e" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:0;line-height:25px;color:#ffffff; background-color:#fe513e !important;" mc:edit="newsletter_title_1">The Latest News for October 2018</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" bgcolor="#fe513e" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px; background-color: #fe513e;" class="fix_height"> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="30" bgcolor="#fe513e" style="background-color: #fe513e !important" class="hide"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: `colspan` doesnt work properly across email clients. Try to use tables inside tables.

Comment: @Syfer is right. If nothing else, duplicate the same `td` structure as you have with the rest of the table.